# Falling segment reunites with other segments with a probability, determine the expected medium length of the segment

Tags: algorithm

This is a really tough problem, just a heads-up.

---

We have `N` segments, numbered from `1` to `N` and defined by their left and right points, `{Left[i],Right[i]}`.

The `i`-th segment is at height `N-i`. The first segment (the highest one) starts falling while the others remain fixed. If during the fall a segment `i` intersects another segment `j` in at least one point, then the two will reunite with the probability `P[j]/Q[j]`, and the obtained segment will keep falling. From the reunion of two segments, `{A,B}` and `{C,D}`, the obtained segment will be `{min(A,C),max(B,D)}`.

You are asked to determine the expected medium length of the first segment (i.e after it reached a height smaller than the height of any of the other segments). If this answer is a rational number `U/V`, you are asked to determine `X` such that `X*V=U (mod 10^9+7)`

---

Restrictions :

- `0 < P < Q < 1 000`
- `0 < Left < Right < 1 000 000`
- `N ≤ 100 000`
- `time : 2.5 sec`
- `memory : 32768 kbytes`

`

---

The input contains `N` on the first line, then on the following `N` lines there are 4 integers : `Left, Right, P, Q,` representing the `i`-th segment `[Left, Right]` with a probability `P/Q` to reunite with the falling segment.
Example:

```
input:
5
35 64 58 873
41 70 407 729
18 90 165 628
10 57 33 104
60 69 152 466

output:
779316733
```

The answer is approximately 49.813963.

---

Comment: Have you attempted this problem? Do you have any code?

Comment: I've only thought about it, so there's no code, and I don't have any worthwhile ideas other than a brute-force approach.

Comment: What does the expected medium length mean? Is it just expected value of the length?

Comment: I don't think so, no, otherwise it wouldn't have said medium. Plus the points' positions are determined by integers. In the example the answer is a rational nunmber, aprox. 49.81, and there's no segment expected to be that long. I think it's rather an arithmetic mean of all the expected lengths times their respective probability of outcome.

Answer (score 1):

### Idea 1

The length of the final segment is R-L where R is the location of the right end, and L is the location of the left end.

Expectation is a linear operation so

E(length) = E(R) - E(L)

We can compute E(R) and E(L) separately, then combined the results.

### Idea 2

We can iteratively compute the PDF for the position of the left end.

It starts off being at the left end of the first segment (Left[1]) with probability 1.

When it falls past segment i, there will be an interesting collision if the left end is between Left[i] and Right[i].  We define an interesting collision to be one that affects the position of the left end.

The key point here is that if we need to know the current position of the right end to determine if there is a collision, then it is not an interesting collision!  This is because if we need to know the right end, then the segment i must be completely to the right of the start point, and therefore it does not affect the position of the left edge.

So to update the PDF we collect up all the probability mass between Left[i] and Right[i], multiply by the probability of collision, and add the result to Left[i].  (The existing mass in those locations is scaled down by the probability of collision.)

### Idea 3

At the moment we have an O(n^2) algorithm made of n iterations of O(n) to count and modify the mass in each range.

However, we can use a data structure such as a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to allow us to perform each iteration in O(logn) time for a total time complexity of O(nlogn).